# Force app to install on internal storage

Tags: android, installation, internal-storage

I want my app to be installable only on internal storage.
I have tried two options:

1. Not specifying any storage preference in the manifest (**the Docs say that this forces the app to install only to internal storage**)
2. Explicitly specifying `android:installLocation="internalOnly"` in the manifest

In both cases, when I try to install it on a tablet that's running Android 4.4.2, Kernel 3.4.67, and having an SD card, it prompts me to select whether the app should be installed on Tablet Storage or the SD card.
The tablet has ample free internal storage (9 GB). The default write disk is also set to Internal Storage.

Is there any way to bypass this prompt and install to internal storage after the user approves the permissions needed by the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install), the flag you are using should not allow install on the SDCARD or any external storage. This appears to be a bug.

Post at the [bug location](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34880) to help give it attention.